Why do I see different declension tables for the same noun in different sources?
I debated whether to post this question on Meta but ultimately decided to post it on the main site because at its core it is a question about declension more than it is about dictionaries. Nonetheless, please let me know if it is better suited for Meta.
At my current level I still rely heavily on English-German dictionaries and resources, which means rather than more authoritative dictionaries like Duden I consult such resources as Collins, English Wiktionary a lot more. Curiously I have come across conflicting declension tables on these sites. Often the declension tables I see on Collins and Wikipedia don't agree, leaving me at a loss as to what to do.
The noun Name is the newest instance that I have come across. Collins has 2 declension tables for the same word, with no explanation whatsoever. Neither of those tables seem consistent with what I have seen. I learned the nominative as Name while the dative and accusative should be Namen, and Wiktionary seems to agree.
And this isn't the first time I've been confused by conflicting declensional information. Why does it happen? What's up with Collins' declension tables? I know that sometimes obsolete or dated usage finds its way into declension tables like the dative -e, but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

When I look at the table in collin's, it doesn't make sense to me.

When it has two entries in a dictionary, it's likely not "the same noun".

I had that with Collins as well when I had wanted to give some German learner advice. Their declension tables are crap. Most likely they are software generated.

Also try the German Wiktionary, on https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Name and https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Namen in this case

It's most definitely not suited for meta, because meta is for questions about this site, not about dictionaries

@infinitezero Well, on most other language related stacks, meta is the right place to post if you want to ask about learning resources such as dictionaries, translation, textbooks, learning/teaching methodology or comment on those things. And questions about dictionaries will get migrated from the main site to meta on all the language stacks I am familiar with.

@desmo that seems really odd to me. We just have it in the normal one: Resources for learning German

@infinitezero Interesting, but you'll be surprised to know that practice definitely puts German SE in the minority. I will list a few that you may be familiar with. You seem to have accounts on ELL and ELU. Both have strict policies prohibiting such posts on the main site and here are their resource posts and related discussions, all on meta: 1 2 3 4 resource related questions are off topic on those main sites.

@desmo While each stackexchange may organise themselves as they see fit ( I believe ), asking a question on e.g. english.meta show this prompt on the right: "Is your question about the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange community or website?" Clearly, asking about dictionaries or references is not a question about the community or website.

The problem is that Collins is offering two different words, "der Name" and "der Namen". with one declension table for each word.  I've checked in Duden, and it says that usage of "der Namen" is seltener, i.e. uncommon or rare. Your confusion probably arises because most of the rest of the declension is the same for each word.
Unfortunately the way the Collins online entry is written is rather confusing. I've just checked my hard copy Collins German Dictionary and Grammar and that only has "der Name", so that doesn't help either!
I know it seems frightening to tackle an all German dictionary like www.duden.de but I'd strongly recommend it if you have a German word and need to check declensions or conjugations. Just select Wörterbuch, and then search for your word. It will usually list the word you've searched for plus several similar ones (it offered me both Name and Namen when I searched for Name). Select the one you want, then scroll down to Grammatik. It's a great resource!

The declension table Collins gives for der Name is wrong though. Acc sg must be den Namen and dat sg must be dem Namen for that one as well. The only difference between der Name and der Namen is in nom sg.

I think just omitting the form “der Namen” as your printed dictionary does is a very sensible choice for a dictionary with limited space and resources.

Is this a regional thing? I have never come across "der Namen" in nominative, it even sounds wrong to me (well, German has a gazillion of dialects).

Definitely a regional thing, I'd say that the majority of speakers probably don't know this nominative form.

Thank you for pointing that out @Janka . Now I've checked it out, I realise I was not aware that this is one of eight masculine nouns which have an -n added in the accusative and dative singular, and -ns in the gentiive singular.  In case anyone is interested Hammer's German grammar and usage says that these eight are Buchstabe, Friede, Funke, Gedanke, Glaube, Name, Same and Wille.

@RuthMcT: there are a more weak nouns that allow -ns in the genitive singular though. E.g. both des Jungen and des Jungens are common.

You stumbled across two similar, but still different words: der Name and der Namen. Some dictionaries describe them as two separate words, other dictionaries describe them as one word that has two possible forms in nominative singular.

This is the correct declension table for the noun Name:



grammatical case
singular
plural




nominative
der Name
die Namen


genitive
des Namens
der Namen


dative
dem Namen
den Namen


accusative
den Namen
die Namen



This is the correct declension table for the noun Namen:



grammatical case
singular
plural




nominative
der Namen
die Namen


genitive
des Namens
der Namen


dative
dem Namen
den Namen


accusative
den Namen
die Namen



Both nouns mean exactly the same, and they differ only in nominative singular, but they are still two different words. The word der Name is the main form which is much more often used than der Namen, but later is still a correct German noun, it is just used rarely.

What do different dictionaries say about both words?

German Wiktionary
In my personal opinion this is the best dictionary for German words. It has a page for Name and a separate page for Namen, each with a clear declension table.

English Wiktionary
Also English Wiktionary has separate pages for Name and Namen, but there is no declension table for Namen and the declension table for Name exists, but is hidden and must be made visible by clicking on a button.

DWDS (Digitales Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache)
Technically there are two separate links for Name and Namen, but they have identical contents. But DWDS has only a description of the declension, but no explicit declension table.

Duden
Everything said about DWDS is also true for Duden. It has separate links for Name and Namen, but its the same content without explicit declension table.

OVID
There are separate entries for Name and Namen, but this site does not provide any information about grammar. Instead it links to Verbformen for that purpose.

Verbformen
The links for Name and Namen show the exactly identical content with one combined declension table for both words.

Collins
Collins has only a page for Name. The link for Namen immediately redirects to the page for Name. But this page still contains two separate declension tables, one for the word Name and the other for the word Namen. But those tables list the cases in a wired order (there is a canonical order, see next section of my answer). But even worse: It contains wrong entries. Accusative singular is not »den Name« as Collins claims for Name. It is »den Namen«.

wrong (Collins version): Ich höre den Name.
correct: Ich höre den Namen.



My personal advice: Ignore Collins. It contains many errors. Why would you use an English dictionary when you want to look up German words? Collins is often wrong and English Wiktionary is nice, but incomplete. Better use German dictionaries for German words. That makes much more sense. My personal favorites are German Wikipedia  and DWDS.

About the order of grammatical cases in declension tables:
German native speakers learn in school these synonyms:

»1. Fall« (1st case) = »Nominativ«
»2. Fall« (2nd case) = »Genitiv«
»3. Fall« (3rd case) = »Dativ«
»4. Fall« (4th case) = »Akkusativ«

All textbooks about German grammar written for children in Germany, Austria and Switzerland teach these synonyms (source 1, source 2, source 3, source 4, source 5, source 6 and much much more sources). That is why the majority of German native speakers do not say »Leon verwechselt manchmal den Dativ mit dem Akkusativ.« Instead they say: »Leon verwechselt manchmal den dritten mit dem vierten Fall.« But some English dictionaries don't care about the order that every German native speaker has learned in school. All German dictionaries that provide declension tables use the correct order and so does also English Wikipedia. But Collins does not. Collins ignores the canonical order and uses this very different order, that is very confusing:

nominative (1st case)
accusative (4th case)
genitive (2nd case)
dative (3rd case)


All German dictionaries that provide declension tables use the correct order and so does also English Wikipedia. Duden uses NADG: https://www.duden.de/deklination/substantive/Name_Ruf_Benennung_Bezeichnung. The reasoning is given in the Duden grammar, 10th edition, paragraph numbers 1014 and 1017 (or 217 in the 8th/9th edition). (I would also question that the correct order and the order that is taught are one and the same; German isn't Latin.)

www.duden.de does give the full declension table (see David Vogt's link in his comment here).  In the main entry for Name, go to the section headed Grammatik and click on  Zur Deklinationstabelle des Substantivs Na­me
